# .net 6 MVC Razor site - loginPartial links don't open the page, routing issue? How can I fix this?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Basic site from the create project wizard, I added the Identity scaffold like I have done in the past.

Added the partial to include the _LoginPartial on my template nav bar. However, the links don't open the page.

[image]

[image]

It stays on the current page and the Areas are there.

[image]

The links look default and I haven't changed them.
[image]

If I go to /Identity/Account/Login it renders a 404. Is there any special routing I need to do? I thought it does this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to add app.MapRazorPages(); to the Program.cs

The app is not smart enough to add when adding the Identity scaffold to the application.